# Grails uploaded image not available

Tags: grails

I am uploading an image into the web-apps-folder. It is processed and the upload works fine. 
After the upload I redirect the user to a page where the image should be shown via

```
<g:img...
```

The path is correct but the image seems not to be available. When I wait a few seconds and reload the page the image appears. Does Grails do some caching or so?

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Grails version is 2.3.4

Comment: Sounds like the resource plugin is doing it's thing. What version of Grails are you running? I suspect that's it.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you shouldn't upload images to a volatile directory like the web-apps folder.  When you deploy a new WAR, that folder will be overwritten entirely and you'll lose all the uploads.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore: it is Grails 2.3.4. Do you have any solutions for it? Would be great!

Comment: @Gregg: thank you for this hint! I will refactor it asap.